# Hidding/showing divs with JavaScript with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

I am trying to make something similar to the header section of [this](http://aestheclinicbeauty.com/?ln=bg&page=c) site, and can't quite get it to work. I would like someone to help me with the following:

Here is my example code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color1"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color3" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color2"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color1" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color3"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color2" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color3"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color2" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color2"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color1" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="first" class="cube color1"></div>
            <div id="second" class="cube color3" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
    
    setInterval(hide, 2000);

    function switchDivs()
    {
        var first = document.getElementById("first");
        var second = document.getElementById("second");
    }

    function hide() {
        document.getElementById("first").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("second").style.display="block";
    }

    function show() {
        document.getElementById("first").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("second").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65k788u6/)

I don't understand first why it doesn't change all the "first" divs into "second", it changes only the first div. Than the next question is how to make that action repeat over time, preferably more like random timer for each one of the 6 positions/boxes.

Shortly: I need divs with id="first" to be swapped with divs with id="second" , after like 5-10 seconds delay after loading the page. Then after the same delay, I need them to switch back to showing only divs with id="first" and so on... (something like setInterval function).

Comment: unable to get your need! what you actually needed will you mark it?

Comment: `id` must be unique. For your second question,I would combine the two functions hide and show into one called toggle and call it instead of hide with setInterval

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kb8e55cc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() { $(".color-blocks .col-md-4").each(function() { $(this).children().toggle(); }); }, 2000);
```

A simple line of code could be helpful, and in a simpler way.

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/65k788u6/3/

While you use `ids`, those should be unique, so instead use `toggle()` in order to make it look simpler.

Comment: One more thing,
can you give me a brief explanation on toggle(), and should i assign a premade class for animating them or it has to be done with js?

Comment: Toggle() is jquery function, which hides or shows the elements, if the element is visible, it hides, if the element is not visible, then it displays. I belief, I'm clear with it.. :)

Comment: okay i got it, read more about it , and added a 'slow' animation on toggle(),
i have one more problem now, how to get rid of that "fade out" animation on first element? here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c0nevski/jxtbmagv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem is that you have multiple elements with the same ID? getElementById() seems to be returning the first instance that's true and not further with the same ID. I would recommend using getelementsbyclassname() and using classes instead of ID's to describe groups of elements. Updated the fiddle to show it done this way. version 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HTML is invalid. The ID attribute on any element should always be unique within the context of the entire page.
2. Instead of `.getElementById`, which selects only one item (and only by its ID attribute) you can use `.querySelectorAll` to get all elements that match a given CSS query selector (or `.querySelector` to get a single element).
3. I recommend using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` as a general best practice.

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll(".col-md-4");
var indices = getIndices(rows);
setTimeout(flipRows, 5000);

function getIndices() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

function flipRows() {
  if (indices.length == 0) {
    indices = getIndices();
  }
  var index = Math.random() * indices.length >>> 0;
  var randomRow = rows[indices[index]];
  indices.splice(index, 1);
  flipRow(randomRow);  
  setTimeout(flipRows, 5000); // run again in 5 seconds
}

function flipRow(row) {
  var first = row.querySelector(".first");
  var second = row.querySelector(".second");
  if (first.style.display === "none") {
    first.style.display = "block";
    second.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    first.style.display = "none";
    second.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.color1 {  background-color: pink;}
.color2 {  background-color: lightblue;}
.color3 {  background-color: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color1">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color3" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color2">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color1" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color3">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color2" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color3">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color2" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color2">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color1" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="first cube color1">first</div>
      <div class="second cube color3" style="display: none;">second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this helps a lot, the only thing i noticed is that some box will toggle first/second for like 7-8 seconds, and than continues to others.

Comment: @Conevski Good catch! I've updated the code now so that it keeps track of an array of indices that it hasn't toggled yet, so doesn't toggle any row a second time until after it's toggled each other row.